# Asp.Net 5: How to load assembly version from project.json file?

Tags: version, .net-assembly, asp.net-core, project.json

I've the project.json file with a version specified as

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

How can I read it in code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Get the `AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute` from the assembly](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Host/RuntimeEnvironment.cs#L34-L43)

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Comment: Here's an example that shows you how to get the version https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/afeedf0aae464225fae2b5b7ecd2b029dc02bb46/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Host/RuntimeEnvironment.cs#L44-L48

Answer (score 1):

- in your project.json change the "version": "1.1.xxxx"
- then in your razor view, maybe _Layout footer?
  @using System.Reflection
  @{
  ViewData["Version"] = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetCustomAttribute().InformationalVersion;
  }
- then ViewData["Version"]