# Display project version in ASP.NET MVC Core application (RC2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2

How do I display application version from the project.json?
I am using `gulp-bump` to autoincrement version, but I can't show the recent version. Here is what I'm trying:

```
@(Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationVersion)
```

This does not work, it displays "`1.0.0`" instead of real value from `project.json`

I also tried this but it looks like it is no longer works in RC2:

```
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.IApplicationEnvironment appEnv
My version number is @(appEnv.ApplicationVersion)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As per [this announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/171), `IApplicationEnvironment` no longer exists.

You can still access the `ApplicationVersion` statically using:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationVersion
```

---

It works for me. My `project.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0.2",
    // all the rest
}
```

And in my index view, I have the following line at the top:

```
@Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationVersion
```

And I correctly get `1.0.0.2` in the output. And when I change that value and restart (build) the application, the new version is shown there.

Comment: sorry, my question was not clear enoguh: I am already using that, but it displays 1.0.0.0 instead  of expected 1.0.0.2

Comment: thanks! how do you bump project version (automatically)?

Comment: I never used `gulp-bump` so no idea how that works. It should be enough to just modify the version in `project.json` and the rebuild the app.

Comment: thanks.  gulp-bump does not support 4-number versions strings :( that is the reason

Comment: Oh, I see, that’s a shame! Although I guess four digit versions are not valid according to [semver](http://semver.org/), so you should probably (maybe?) avoid them in .NET Core projects (since it aims to follow semver).

Comment: Hah, I’m glad you figured it out :)

Comment: I added `.TrimEnd('0','.')` to remove trailing '.0's. As long as my third set is nonzero, I get the 3 places without the extra trailing .0. Wish it was smart enough to leave it off when you're using 3 number strings.

Comment: This doesn't work in dotnet 1.0.0. Gives you "File version" which `dotnet publish --version-suffix xxx` doesn't change. What it actually does change is "Product version" but I have no idea how to get this one.

Comment: Fair warning: This gives you the version of the *executing application*, which is not necessarily the version number of the current assembly (assuming the current assembly is a DLL). When I ran this, I got the version of NUnit that I ran the test under...

Answer (score 23):

Since [Platform Abstractions were obly shipped with ASP.NET Core 1](https://github.com/aspnet/PlatformAbstractions) and has been removed from ASP.NET Core 2 and up, if you're using version 2 or above, you must replace this row:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationVersion
```

with this one:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version
```

as specified in "Replacing API usage" section of the previous linked page.

Comment: This doesn't return the suffixed version either.

Answer (score 14):

I used a different approach, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32826759/2571926) which gave me a SemVer version (1.0.0) which is actually in my `project.json` and not 1.0.0.0, which is returned by accepted answer. So the code would be:

```
var runtimeVersion = typeof(Startup)
            .GetTypeInfo()
            .Assembly
            .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()
            .InformationalVersion;
```

It returns correct suffixed versions as well, i.e. something like "2.0.1-dev01"

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me for .NET Core 2.0.5.

Code:

```
var assemblyVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<System.Reflection..AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().InformationalVersion;
Console.WriteLine(assemblyVersion);
```

myproject.csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>1.0.0.1</VersionPrefix>
    <VersionSuffix>alpha</VersionSuffix>
</PropertyGroup>
```

outputs

```
1.0.0.1-alpha
```

Comment: You can also simply use <Version>1.0.0.1-alpha</Version>.

Answer (score 3):

If you end up here and you are trying to manage project versions through the solution version.

Adding a `Directory.Build.props` file to the solution directory containing:

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>1.2.3</VersionPrefix>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Will set the Version property of all included projects that 'Get version from parent solution'.

Not ideal, but it allows you to manage the version in a single place for a version locked multi-project solution.

Comment: This worked perfectly for the 'Get version from parent solution' situation - thanks!