# asp.net core 2 mvc get application version

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'd like to display the project's version, captured in the Solution's options:

[image]

which is saved in the `.SLN` file:

```
GlobalSection(MonoDevelopProperties) = preSolution
    version = 20180325.0
EndGlobalSection
```

in my application's `/Home/About` view.

To do so, I get the version information in the `HomeController`'s `About` action:

```
public IActionResult About()
{
    Version version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version;
    ViewData["Version"] = version;

    return View();
}
```

Then add the data to the `About.cshtml` view:

```
<h2>About</h2>

<h3>General</h3>
<div>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>Version</dt><dd><code>@ViewData["Version"]</code></dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

What is actually displayed, is something else:

[image]

[Display project version in ASP.NET MVC Core application (RC2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798075/display-project-version-in-asp-net-mvc-core-application-rc2#37798175) suggests that you can get this from the `project.json` file, which is not in the project.

What's the recommended approach to display a version?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the static property 
`Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationVersion`

You can also use it in your razor view by adding an `@` beforehand.