# Get Asp.Net Core 2 MVC ReleaseVersion

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to get the text (`2018.09.06`) of the Version attribute of my Asp.Net Core 2 MVC project, which is captured in the project's options dialog:

[image]

The value is contained in the `ReleaseVersion` element in project's `.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Project Foo</RootNamespace>
    <ReleaseVersion>2018.09.06</ReleaseVersion>
    <UserSecretsId>[GUID here]</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

I've tried this:

```
var version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

But it returns `1.0.0.0`.

I'm using .Net Core 2.0 Framework.

Note: the answers to [Display project version in ASP.NET MVC Core application (RC2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798075/display-project-version-in-asp-net-mvc-core-application-rc2#37798175) don't work.

Comment: It's strange that the schema definition does not have a `ReleaseVersion` element . If I change the `ReleaseVersion` to `Version`  , it will work .

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same problem here, I always get 1.0.0.0. I even dumped the assembly and did not find the ReleaseVersion anywhere in it. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I'm dealing with this right now, have you made any progress on this? In my case, and maybe yours, I have each project in my solution set to delegate versioning to the solution. As far as I can tell, that is what causes the ReleaseVersion attribute to show up and there doesn't appear any way to access the ReleaseVersion attribute from the csproj file.

Comment: I made an issue for this: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2700

Answer (score 0):

I added a `/PropertyGroup/VersionPrefix` element to my project's `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <VersionPrefix>1.19.2</VersionPrefix>
  <VersionSuffix></VersionSuffix>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then get the value:

```
string Version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().InformationalVersion.ToString()
```

The value cannot be set by the project's Options UI, as far as I can tell.

Honestly, I'm confused why there is a UI for a separate version number (the one referenced in my question) that can't be accessed by the API.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2700#issuecomment-491025782

Add a `Directory.Build.props` file to your solution folder and manage the version there instead of through the UI.

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>1.19.2</VersionPrefix>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I tend to think the VS tooling should be better about this, but as long as I only have one place to manage this value this is a significant improvement over the alternative.